# Json object in javascript Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, json, codeigniter

This is the Jquery that calls the function in controller. But it is not able to read the Json_encoded object. I am using codeigniter. Why?

```
 $(this).ajaxSubmit({ 
                    type : "POST",
                    url: '../index.php/user/signin',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
                    cache : false,
                    dataType:'json',
                    success : function(data){ 
                        data = $.trim(data);
                        alert(data);
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                        alert(obj.Condition);
                    },
                    error: function(){

                    }
```

Controller

```
$arr = array('Condition' => $condition, 'Message' => $msg);

// header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Make sure that CSRF protection is not enabled by default. If so, pass the csrf token by ajax call to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `eval` instead `parseJSON`

In js:

```
  $(this).ajaxSubmit({ 
                type : "POST",
                url: '../index.php/user/signin',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
                cache : false,
                dataType:'json',
                success : function(data){ 
                    data = $.trim(data);
                    alert(data);
                    var obj = eval('(' + data+ ')');

                    alert(obj.Condition);
                },
                error: function(){

                }
```

I think also that it is not necessary to use $.trim to process response data

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
url: <?=site_url('user/signin')?>,
```

If you are not posting anything you can simply use jquery getjson.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

It works fine.

check browser console, and tell me any errors are there.